# How to make request to endpoints exposed with AWS using iAM authentication?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm new to AWS and I need help.

I have some endpoints (`GET - POST /endpoint`) that are exposed by AWS and my client documented for me.
To call any endpoint I need to authenticate with IAM (my client gave me the `secret_key` and the `access_key`).

I guess with those 2 keys I need to obtain an access token that I need to pass as header authorization to the request.

I'm using `node.js`. How can I obtain the access token so that I can make the request (I guess with some library like `axios`)?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: What kind of service is exposing the endpoint?

Comment: it's a REST API

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use the [AnomalyInnovations/sigV4Client](https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/sigV4Client) and the related [blog post](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/connect-to-api-gateway-with-iam-auth.html):

> A standalone client for signing API Gateway requests for Signature Version 4.